# How to create copy of animation

Tags: animation

Hi how can i create a copy of animation. In adobe Flash we make a symbol a movie clip. For more information about what is a movie clip watch this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=65EqB52GH-Q)
If we make a movie clip and once drag and drop that movie clip on the art board we can create many copies. Is there any option or how can i create copies just drag and drop and get that animation. Any suggestion or Help Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to the *action editor*. Press **Push Down**. The action is moved to the *NLA editor*.

[image]

Open the NLA editor. Here you see the Action Strip. You can change it's start and end frame. You can move it around with <kbd>G</kbd>. You can add actions strips with <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd><kbd>A</kbd>. You can set an action strip to repeat.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In Blender whenever you program an animation you create a datablock called "action", which contains all the informations about location, rotation, scale or other parameters of the object or armature's bones involved in the animation.
This datablock can be managed in the action editor: select the object or the armature you've animated, open a  dopesheet window, in the dropdown menu set it to action editor: you will see the action dopesheet.

[image]If you want to apply your animation to another object, just select the object and select your animation in the second dropdown menu of the action editor.

If you want to modify the action you've made, you must click on the little number (i.e. 2) near the name of the action: the number tells you that 2 (or more) object are sharing the same animation (so if you modify the action all objects will modify their behaviour). Clicking the number will create a copy of the animation datablock that can be freely edited, without affecting the first animation.

In the action editor you can select, copy, cut and paste groups of keyframes in the usual way (Ctrl C,X,V for Windows), pasting the selection at the green timeline position.